# Show that if a DFA accepts all words of length < 2n then it accepts any word

Tags: finite-automata

Is it true that if a given DFA $M = \langle Q, \Sigma, \delta, q_0, F\rangle$ with $|Q| = n$ accepts all strings $w \in \Sigma^*$ such that $|w|\leq 2n$ then it accepts any $w \in \Sigma^*$ ?

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: Also, there is a discrepancy between the title (smaller than $2n$) and the body (at most $2n$).

Comment: Are you interested in a complete answer? By the way, $\lt n$ is enough.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that a DFA with $n$ states accepts some word $w$ whose length is at least $n$. According to the pumping lemma, we can decompose $w$ as $xyz$, where $|xy| \leq n$, $y \ne \epsilon$, and the DFA accepts $xy^iz$ for all $i \geq 0$.

See if you can use this to develop a criterion for your problem (determining whether a DFA accepts all strings by checking all strings up to a particular length).